# How to categories output from Mysql using PHP & avoid repetitive values?

Tags: php, mysql

**I have these tables in mysql DB & using php to get the output.**

**event**(ID,eventName)

**t1photo** (ID, date,path,fileName,eventID)

**I use this bit of code to view images with their events names.**

```
$selectPhotos = mysql_query (" select  event_name, photoName from t1photo left join  event on  event.event_ID = t1photo.eventID order by event_name");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectPhotos )) {

    foreach($row as $key => $value){

        if($key=='event_name')
        {
        echo $value;
        }
        if ($key=='photoName')
        {
        echo"<img src='uploaded/$value' alt='some_text'>";
        }

        }
}
```

the output is something like this :

event_name1 photoName event_name1 photoName event_name2 photoName event_name2 photoName etc..

I want the out put to be some thing like this

event_name1 photoName photoName event_name2 photoName photoName

i.e I want to categories the photoName by the eventName.

Comment: And if you know the names of your columns, why `foreach` over them all?  Ie just access them directly as `$row['event_name']` and `$row['photoName']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about saving the category as you go and comparing the category listed in the current row w/ the category listed in the last row you processed, like so:

```
$last_event = "";
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectPhotos )) {

  foreach($row as $key => $value){

    if($key=='event_name' && $value != $last_event )
    {
      echo $value;
      $last_event = $value;
    }
    else if ($key=='photoName')
    {
      echo"<img src='uploaded/$value' alt='some_text'>";
    }

  }
}
```